# Eclipse gets "IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred." when I'm trying create a soap client

Tags: java, eclipse, ws

I'm trying to create a soap web service client and when I go to *File > New > Other > WebServices > WebServiceClient*.

I'm getting this error:

```
IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.
  loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.consumption.ui.wsrt.CXFWebServiceClient.run(Lorg/eclipse/wst/common/environment/IEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/wst/ws/internal/wsrt/IContext;Lorg/eclipse/wst/ws/internal/wsrt/ISelection;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/wst/command/internal/env/core/ICommandFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/jst/ws/internal/cxf/consumption/ui/wsrt/CXFWebServiceClient, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/wst/command/internal/env/core/ICommandFactory used in the signature
      java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.consumption.ui.wsrt.CXFWebServiceClient.run(Lorg/eclipse/wst/common/environment/IEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/wst/ws/internal/wsrt/IContext;Lorg/eclipse/wst/ws/internal/wsrt/ISelection;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/wst/command/internal/env/core/ICommandFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/jst/ws/internal/cxf/consumption/ui/wsrt/CXFWebServiceClient, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/wst/command/internal/env/core/ICommandFactory used in the signature
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.creation.ui.wsrt.CXFWebServiceRuntime.getWebServiceClient(CXFWebServiceRuntime.java:32)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.runtime.ClientRuntimeSelectionWidgetDefaultingCommand.setDefaultsForExtension(ClientRuntimeSelectionWidgetDefaultingCommand.java:1457)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.runtime.ClientRuntimeSelectionWidgetDefaultingCommand.execute(ClientRuntimeSelectionWidgetDefaultingCommand.java:301)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:421)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:361)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:256)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:296)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:260)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:93)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(WizardPageManager.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getStartingPage(WizardPageManager.java:82)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.getStartingPage(DynamicWizard.java:366)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:122)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:911)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:468)
      at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
      at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4173)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3986)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3585)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:260)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:280)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:95)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
      at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:318)
      at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:252)
      at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
      at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:498)
      at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
      at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:584)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:653)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:443)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$2(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:386)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1199)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1491)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4879)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_CHAR(Tree.java:5992)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4761)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5987)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4812)
      at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3583)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
```

I'm using Eclipse 2019.09 and apache cxf2.x V3.3.5 and GlassFish 5.0.1 and jdk 8.
I added apache runtime to Eclipse's preferences.
I searched allot and none of existing solutions solved my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like [Eclipse bug 288912](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288912).

Comment: That's Null pointer exception, but this is loader constraint violation.

Comment: Sure, but the `IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.` error happen in both cases in the same situation at allmost the same location (`org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand`), which might be caused by different versions (by the way, is there a reason why you are using an outdated Eclipse version?). However, the solution for an issue found in open source software is to make sure it has been reported and to help to fix it. Up to now, the bug has no votes and has only been confirmed by three people in 10 years.

Comment: I'm using eclipse 2019.09 it is almost up-to-date.

Comment: So, congratulations to the almost successful creation of a SOAP web service client with _"eclipse 2019.09"_ (which is almost the right term for _Eclipse 2019-09_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse and that error disappeared!
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
I recommend clean install rather than update.

Comment: IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.
  
      java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.ClasspathShortener.getLaunchConfigurationName(ClasspathShortener.java:377)